# Solidity assembly error: Builtin function "gas" must be called

Tags: assembly, solidity, evm

I'm writing a proxy contract in Solidity. To forward incoming calls in my fallback function I'm using inline assembly code. I'm a student and the code below is the code my instructor wrote in the tutorial.

I'm receiving the following error with my code though:

> Builtin function "gas" must be called.

I'm assuming that Solidity has evolved since the making of the tutorial, but I cannot find anything online (google or the docs).

Here is the code:

```
assembly {
        let result := delegatecall(gas, implementation, add(data, 0x20), mload(data), 0, 0)
        let size := returndatasize
        let ptr := mload(0x40)
        returndatacopy(ptr, 0, size)
        switch result   
        case 0 {revert(ptr, size)}  
        default{return(ptr, size)}  
}
```

The error refers to the word "gas" in line 2 which is underlined in red.
Has something changed?

Answer (score 5):

In older versions of the docs (e.g. [v0.4.24](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.4.24/assembly.html)) it says that:

> For opcodes that do not take arguments, the parentheses can be omitted.

However, [newer versions](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.7/assembly.html) of the docs link to [a separate page](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.7/yul.html#yul) for the intermediate language, now called Yul. And on that page, the opcodes are now also referred to as *"builtin functions"*, and it appears that omitting the parentheses is no longer allowed.

So you should most likely use `gas()` instead of `gas`.